# Recall Score != Manual Calculation using confusion_matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have encountered an issue where the recall score obtained using `recall_score(y, y_pred)` does not match the value calculated manually using `confusion_matrix`.

Not only that, but recall is exactly the same value as specificity which I've also calculated manually below.

Here is the relevant code I'm using:

```py
recall = recall_score(y, y_pred) # <-- different score

conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
tn, fp, fn, tp = conf_matrix.ravel()
manual_recall = tp / (tp + fn) # <-- to this score
specificity = tn / (tn + fp) # <-- and is the same as the score above
```

Here's an example of a confusion matrix as printed in the terminal where this happens:

```
[[34  6]
 [20 20]]
```

Sci Kit Recall: 0.85
Manual Recall: 0.5

or

```
[[29 11]
 [ 9 31]]
```

Sci Kit Recall: 0.725
Manual Recall: 0.775

**Problem:**

Recall as returned by scikit-learn and manual recall do not produce the same value.

**Question:**

Why might the `recall_score` and manual calculation using `confusion_matrix` yield different results for the recall score?

**More information...**

- It is a binary classification problem.
- I'm using the default threshold for `recall_score`.
- I've tried to determine whether the confusion table is accurate (it is).

Comment: Is your **positive** label `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by desertnaut, this is an issue with different labels being considered positive.
[`recall_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html) by default considers `1` as being the positive label.

> **pos_label : *int, float, bool or str, default=1***

You can change this:

```py
# Assuming your binary classes are 1 and 2
recall = recall_score(y, y_pred, pos_label=2)
```

On the other hand, [`conf_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) uses the labels in sorted order by default, therefore the positive label is the highest value.

> If `None` is given, those that appear at least once in `y_true` or `y_pred` are used in sorted order.

You can also change this:

```py
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred, labels=[1,2])
```

It is recommended to always set the parameters `pos_label` and `labels` to control the consistency of the metrics.